# HttpListener как вернуть файл с русским названием

Tags: c#, кодировка, httplistener

сервер должен вернуть файл на скачивание.  с англ названиями все ок, с русскими не могу добиться присвоения нормального назания.
пример:

```
byte[] fromb64 = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
string fname = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fromb64);

Console.WriteLine("Decoded base64 = " + fname);// тут все нормально

response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(fname));// а тут нет. получается бурда из символов
response.ContentLength64 = file_Stream.Length;
response.SendChunked = false;
response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
```

пробовал прямо подставить

```
response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"файл.jpg\"");
```

получаю D09;.jpg

есть решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP заголовки поддерживают только ASCII кодировку.

Согласно [RFC-2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183) такой заголовок, включающий в себя не-ASCII символы, должен быть закодирован согласно [RFC-2184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2184).

> Parameter values longer than 78 characters, or which contain non-ASCII characters, MUST be encoded as specified in [RFC 2184].

Сам же RFC-2184 устарел и заменен на [RFC-2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231).

Например, если имя файла "картинка.jpg", и вы кодируете с помощью UTF-8, то получится так

```cs
string fileName = "картинка.jpg";
string fileNameUrlEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" + fileNameUrlEncoded);
```

На выходе получится

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0.jpg
```

*После `UTF-8` два апострофа, а не кавычки.*

Вот еще полезная [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93551/12888024).

Comment: а зачем удалили первый ответ? я по нему решил проблему. но этот засчитаю взамен

Comment: @axmed2004 потому что он был не по стандарту. Например, если вы отправите такой ответ браузеру, он вас не поймет. Изучите стандарт, и сделайте по требованиям, чтобы было совместимо с браузерами.

Comment: ну не знаю. мой браузер оказался понятливым

Comment: @axmed2004 я дополнил ответ примером